# Delay on updating the state by one character

Tags: reactjs, input, onchange

I have 4 input fields where I am entering the amount and based on that amount I am getting the rate.

Scenario: when user is filling in the field, for example inputing 20000 in input1 the rate has to be 116.04 but instead of that user gets 11.60. So there is an obvious delay of 1 character and as soon as I put 0 in the input2 field I get the correct rate which is 116.04
This is not acceptable for me as I have 4 fields overall and numbers are always different. How can I fix it???
This is my state:

```
 this.state = {
            input: {
                amount: '20000',
                inputField1: '',
                inputField2: '',
                inputField3: '',
                inputField4: '',
                ...window.input,
            },
```

These are my input fields:

```
 <Input className="col-8"
                value={this.state.input.inputField1}
                onChange={(event) => {
                this.updateInputField("inputField1", event.target.value);
                }}/>
<Input className="col-8"
                value={this.state.input.inputField2}
                onChange={(event) => {
                this.updateInputField("inputField2", event.target.value);
                }}/>
<Input className="col-8"
                value={this.state.input.inputField3}
                onChange={(event) => {
                this.updateInputField("inputField3", event.target.value);
                }}/>
<Input className="col-8"
                value={this.state.input.inputField4}
                onChange={(event) => {
                this.updateInputField("inputField4", event.target.value);
                }}/>
```

These are my methods:

```
updateInput = (key, value) => {
    let input = {...this.state.input};
    input[key] = value;
    window.input = input;
    this.calculate(input);
};

updateInputField= (key, value) => {
    let {input} = this.state;
    let sum = +input.inputField1 + +input.inputField2 + +input.inputField3 + +input.inputField4
    input[key] = value;
    this.setState({input});
    window.input = input;
    this.updateInput("amount",sum)// this is where I am getting the delay
};
```

I am trying to should the total Amount using this state:

```
<p>{this.state.input.amount}</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `updateInputField` function - Instead of calculating the `sum` *before* updating `input[key]`, try updating updating `input[key]`, **then** calculate `sum`. Like this:

```js
// first, update 'input' with the new value
input[key] = value;

// next, calculate the new sum
let sum = +input.inputField1 + +input.inputField2 + +input.inputField3 + +input.inputField4
```

The "Delay" you're seeing is due to the fact that your code follows this order:

1. Gets old `input` values from state
2. Calculates the sum of the old `input` values
3. Updates `input` (at the current `key` that got updated) with the `value`

   - This needs to be #2, not #3!
4. Sets the updated `input` in state
5. Calls `this.updateInput`

So your new `updateInputField` function would look like this:

```js
updateInputField= (key, value) => {
    let {input} = this.state;
    // first, update 'input' with the new value
    input[key] = value;

    // next, calculate the new sum
    let sum = +input.inputField1 + +input.inputField2 + +input.inputField3 + +input.inputField4

    this.setState({input});
    window.input = input;
    this.updateInput("amount",sum)
};
```